# SQL Server UPDATE statement reports correct affected row count but not updating data in table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am facing a strange problem. My application sends an `UPDATE` command as shown below. It reports correct affected row count. But occasionally it does not change anything in the table despite correctly reported affected row count. Command is not in a transaction, and I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

```
UPDATE InRecordDetails 
SET RecordStatus = 10 
WHERE Id IN (789, 790, 791, 794, 792, 793, 795, 796)
```

Edit: I am using Dapper, here is the method issuing update command:

```
public void UpdateInRecordDetailStatus(List<int> idList, RecordStatus status)
    {
        using (var cn = new SqlConnection(_localDbConnStirng))
        {
            var csv = idList.Aggregate("", (current, id) => current + (id + ","));
            csv = csv.Substring(0, csv.Length - 1);//strip last comma

            var sqlText = String.Format("UPDATE InRecordDetails set RecordStatus = {0} where Id in ({1})",(int) status, csv);
            var log = LogManager.GetLogger("DBLogger");
            
            cn.Open();
            var rowsAffected = cn.Execute(sqlText);
            log.DebugFormat("Sending {0} after EmailerJob fired. AFFECTED {1} rows!", sqlText,rowsAffected);                
            cn.Close();
        }
    }
```